# Fade out siblings in a list (non jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I've created a script to fade out all items in a list when one element in the list is hovered.

I've sort of got it to work - but the last item in the list doesn't fade in (when the last item in the list is hovered all items are faded) - the rest of the list though works correctly.

My script is here -

```
var activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

    for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
    activeItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", fadeOutItems, false);

    activeItems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", resetListStyles, false);

    function fadeOutItems() {
        for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
            this.setAttribute("class", "item fade-in");
            activeItems[i].setAttribute("class", "item fade-out");
        }
    }

    function resetListStyles() {
        for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
            activeItems[i].setAttribute("class", "item");
        }
    }

}
```

And have created a fiddle here -

https://jsfiddle.net/1opq1eyj/1/

Any advice on where i'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Also would be grateful for any advice on how the script could have been improved upon.

Thanks,

Comment: put this line ' this.setAttribute("class", "item fade-in");' after loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong ordering

First you should deselect all and then you should make `this.setAttribute`

```
 function fadeOutItems() {
        for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
             activeItems[i].setAttribute("class", "item fade-out");
             this.setAttribute("class", "item fade-in");
        }
    }
```

update [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1opq1eyj/2/)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Özgür!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the fade-in attribute is set each time inside the loop. For the last item, that means that activeItems[i] will overwrite that last class-setting. The 'fade-in' setting can be placed outside the loop.

```
function fadeOutItems() {
        for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
            activeItems[i].setAttribute("class", "item fade-out");
        }
        this.setAttribute("class", "item fade-in");
    }
```

---

As for the possible alternatives. The same can be done with pure css with a single selector:

```
  .item-list:hover > .item:not(:hover) {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

This sets the opacity for all `.item`s inside the `.item-list` div, except the one being hovered. [fiddle Option 1](https://jsfiddle.net/1opq1eyj/3/)

---

However, since width of the container is 100%, the effect may trigger somewhat to soon, (depending on the total layout).
To be on the safe side, you can add an extra class to the container once one of the child items is hovered with JS (as long as CSS parent selectors are not in basic support) and base the css on that class:
JS:

```
let activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item'),
    itemList = document.querySelector('.item-list');

 for (i = 0; i < activeItems.length; i++) {
    activeItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){itemList.classList.add('fade');}, false);
    activeItems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){itemList.classList.remove('fade');}, false);
}
```

CSS:

```
.fade:hover > .item:not(:hover) {
        opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[Fiddle option 2](https://jsfiddle.net/1opq1eyj/4/)